# No value returned from TextBox when removing readonly attribute on client side script

Tags: c#, asp.net

Initially I have a textbox with an attribute readonly = true. When I use a asyncFileUpload OnClientUploadCompleted, I successfully remove the attribute readonly on my asp textbox(Client side). But when I trying to retrieve the value from my textbox on server side it returns an empty string or null even it has a value.
Here's the client side script

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function OnClientUploadCompleteFn(){document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSponsorFileDesc').removeAttribute('ReadOnly');
    }
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtSponsorFileDesc" runat="server" MaxLength="100" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="70px"  style="resize:none;"></asp:TextBox>
```

Is this a bug or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: If you are just reading from your Textbox why do you need to turn off ReadOnly? The ReadOnly property only stops the user from Editing the textbox from the UI. How are you setting the textbox? And Reading from it?

Comment: Have u assigned values to the textbox in javascript?

Comment: wait, I'll update my post

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that ASP.NET expects no value because as far as it's concerned (on the server side) it's still read-only.  I would recommend not doing anything with the ReadOnly property in ASP.NET and keep it purely on the client.  Set it to readonly with JQuery when the page is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#textBox").attr('readonly','readonly');
});
```

and then make it active on the client-side when the time is right:

```
$("#textBox").removeAttr('readonly');
```

Comment: +1: `TextBox.LoadPostData` ignores the submitted form value if the `ReadOnly` value that was persisted in view state is `true`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I found out that you just have to include the readonly property in the asp code. +1 for the effort though.